# filled contour plot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a filled contour plot in R.  My data labels x and y are length 20 vectors, and my z matrix is 20 by 20.  The following is my code, with the filled.contour command copied directly from the r help(filled.contour) file, just with extraneous parameters removed:

```
x <- seq(1,5)
y <- seq(1,5)
cells <- c(1,4,9,16,25,1,4,9,16,25,1,4,9,16,25,1,4,9,16,25,1,4,9,16,25)
z <- matrix(cells,nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
filled.contour(x,y,z,nlevels = 20,col = cm.colors(19))
```

Comment: If you specify `color.palette`, no need to provide `col`. If you do so, the vector of colors given by `col`, will override `color.palette`. ([source](http://127.0.0.1:20325/library/graphics/html/filled.contour.html))

Comment: @Pascal, OK, if I don't specify col, then I get a plot with 20 levels, but only 3 colors.   My goal is to have 20 levels with 19 different colors.   If I don't specify color.palette, but do specify col =..., then obviously I get the same error message about variable color.palette not being found.

Comment: Yes, `color.palette` is not an R function you can directly call. You can use [one of these functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html) to create the vector `col`. Or use the `[RColorBrewer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html)` package.

Comment: @Pascal  OK, so based on that page I tried: filled.contour(x,y,z,nlevels = 20,col=cm.colors(20)), which again generates a contour plot with 20 levels and varying shades of 3 colors, blue, white, and purple.  What I am trying to accomplish is 20 levels with 19 distinct colors for each level between contours.

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum, yes, I read your answer, but if I remove the col = ... parameter then I am left with only 3 colors, not the desired 19.  I understand that I may be misinterpreting the usage instructions, but unfortunately it is unclear to me based on your response what the correct way to interpret them is.

Comment: It's now time to provide a reproducible example, I guess.

Comment: @Mark I updated my answer for your 19 color problem (before I wrote the comment), please check out if it works for you.

Comment: @Pascal, OK, I have edited to my original post to make the example "reproducible".  As you can see, the result includes only 3 different colors.

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum, I edited my original poste to try your suggestion, but as you can see the result only includes 3 colors.

Comment: You have only 5 levels of data. Why do you need 19 colors?

Comment: Never mind, I'll figure it out on my own.

Comment: That is not a very nice way to respond since @Pascal is trying to help you and you seem not to be able to explain your problem detailed for us to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `col =color.palette(length(levels) - 1)`. You have to know that in R manuals, the line that is under **Usage** just shows which parameters are available and next to it the default parameter. Which does not necessarily mean you can write it exactly the same way. So if you leave these parameter, it will automatically take the value that is stated there.

For examples you should check the **Examples** section, which is usually quite rich.

**EDIT**

To get 19 colors you have to write

```
filled.contour(x,y,z,nlevels = 20,col =cm.colors(19))
```

cm.colors is a function that returns n colors. color.palette can not do that for you because it is not a function but a parameter for filled.contour.

Comment: @Mark you should write this comment to your question and not my answer :)

Comment: @Mark but it is clear why it does not work, when you try to use color.palette(length(levels) - 1) which is not a function, like Pascal and I tried to explain to you.